# Using global temporary tables can be a hindrance to performance?

Tags: .net, performance, oracle, architecture

I'm currently reviewing data access code on a .net solution consuming an Oracle 11g database. I found some code whose functionality is to fill a .net collection using data obtained from the database. To fulfill this purpose, the code use this steps at the Data Access Layer:

1. Insert input data in a global temporary table. This data comes from the front end. The front end receives a string and creates a DML insert statement over the global temporary table that is then executed using `OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.
2. Execute the intended procedure. This procedure consumes the global temporary table filled in the previous step to generate the output.
3. Read the data from the global temporary tables in step 2.

This is the first time I see something like that. Although I haven't seen this code running yet, I think this code could have some performance and maintainability issues. Usually I've seen this steps done by writing a procedure implementing the functionality without resorting to global temporary tables.

1. The first approach generates performance problems?
2. Could you reference any autoritative source arguing against the first approach?

Comment: By "temporal table", do you mean "temporary table" (i.e. a global temporary table)?  Or do you mean a table that stores different versions of the same row over time? Or are you potentially referring to a PL/SQL collection using a nested table?

Comment: @JustinCave sorry... I've corrected the question

Comment: Where is the data that is being inserted into the global temporary table coming from?  Is there some query that is being executed in order to retrieve the data?  Or is the data being input into the front end?

Comment: @JustinCave sorry by answering late... It was 20:00 here...

Answer (score 1):

Global temporary tables perform at same speed as ordinary tables. They are written to disk, contains blocks, are loaded in Buffer Cache etc.

They only have some transactional features, [consult docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#autoId12).

How you implement the application, is your choice. Loading data in a table before processing it, can be a strategy if data is big and you can't just keep entirely in memory.
And... you can test these scenarios.